# MS Access select distinct random values

Tags: sql, random, ms-access-2010, distinct

How can I select 4 **distinct** **random** values from the field answer in MS Access table question?

```
SELECT TOP 4 answer,ID FROM question GROUP BY answer ORDER BY rnd(INT(NOW*ID)-NOW*ID)
```

Gives error message:

> Run-time error '3122':  Your query does not include the specified
>   expression 'ID' as part of  an aggregate function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 answer,ID FROM question ORDER BY rnd(INT(NOW*ID)-NOW*ID)
```

Gives error message:

> Run-time error '3093':  ORDER BY clause (rnd(INT(NOW*ID)-NOW*ID))
>   conflicts with  DISTINCT.

Edit:
Tried this:

```
SELECT TOP 4 *
FROM (SELECT answer, Rnd(MIN(ID)) AS rnd_id FROM question GROUP BY answer)  AS A
ORDER BY rnd_id;
```

Seems to work sofar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
SELECT TOP 4 answer
FROM question
GROUP BY answer
ORDER BY Rnd(MIN(ID));
```

I don't think the subquery is necessary.  And including the random value on the `SELECT` doesn't seem useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've creted a simple quiz application 2 years ago, and this is the query that I use to get a random question from the table.

```
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM Questions ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: `NEWID()` is not supported in Access SQL.